# Limit line width without cutting words

Tags: java

I currently use this code to limit lines to 20 characters:

```
if (string.length() % 20 == 0 && string.length() >= 20) {
    this.string += "\n";
}
```

However, it breaks words like this:

```
Hello, my name is Pa
trick
```

How can i prevent this?

Comment: How do you build the string in the first place?

Comment: I just append the letter when its key is pressed
if (keyIsPressed(A)) {
string += "a";
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a regex like this `.{1,20}(\W|$)` to split phrases approaching 20 characters but without splitting on words.

This will work for max 20 characters. If you want to configure the number you can parameterize it in the regular expression like `"(.{1," + max + "}(\\W|$))"` where `max` is your limit.

```
String s = "Hello, my name is Patrick and I have a lot to say, but I will tell you that another day.";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.{1,20}(\\W|$))").matcher(s);
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
    b.append(m.group()).append("\n");
}
System.out.println("-> " + b.toString());
```

Will print out:

```
-> Hello, my name is 
Patrick and I have a 
lot to say, but I 
will tell you that 
another day.
```

**Edit**

I edited the answer above, in fact it was searching for a character not in a word `\W` and in my example the string ended by a `.` but not in yours. I edited the regular expression above so that it works also if the string does end with a character not represented in `\W` by adding a condition on the end of string with `$`.

You can see a runnable example here: http://ideone.com/Nw2aNr

Comment: I couldn't make it work as it should. If i replace the contents of your string with "Hello, how are you doooing misteer", it removes the last word (misteer)

Comment: @PatrickReck See my edit, I slightly modified the regular expression so that it works also if the string end with a regular character (not in `\W`).

Answer (score 3):

Split a string by spaces with `s.split("\\s+")` and then append word by word watching the line 's length.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is some piece of code that is every time a character is appended. So, to fix this you should be doing some more interesting things. The basic idea is this:

1. Line limit detected.
2. Take that last line.
3. Split on whitespaces using `String words[] = line.split("\\s+");`
4. If you have more than one word, then

   - Take a substring of that line using `lastIndexOf(words[words.length - 1]);`, this way that you keep everything except for the last word.
   - Add that last word to a new line.
5. otherwise, break off the word like you do now (by adding a newline)

Comment: I'm really new to Java, perhaps you could extend the answer with a code example? :-)